# Репозиторий больше 2 гб после миграции файлов на лфс && gc --aggressive --prune=now

Tags: git

Достиг лимита в 2 ГБ на битбакете. Выскочило предупреждение о превышении размера хранилища и read-only доступе. 
Мигрировал свой локальный репозиторий на lfs следующим образом.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Migrating repository to LFS using extensions from root `.gitattributes`.

# Get extensions specified in `.gitattributes`:
lfs_extensions=$(cat ./.gitattributes | grep -o '^[^ ]*' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 
's/,$//g')

# Migrate files with given extensions and rewriting history in all local 
branches:
git lfs migrate import --everything --include="$lfs_extensions" --verbose
```

После этого сделал

```
git gc -aggressive --prune=now
```

и проверил после всего этого

```
git count-objects -v -H
```

И оно выдает оно мне

```
count: 0
size: 0 bytes
in-pack: 277884
packs: 1
size-pack: 2.24 GiB
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0 bytes
```

Т.е. размер репозитория - по прежнему 2 гига, и даже стал чуть больше.

Содержимое .gitattributes

```
Assets/Content/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
\# filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpeg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ai filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.raw filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.flac filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mp4 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mov filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.FBX filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.blend filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.skp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.max filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.a filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.exr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pdf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.zip filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.rar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.7z filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tar.gz filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dll filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.unitypackage filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.aif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ttf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.rns filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.reason filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lxo filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Image

# Audio
# Video
# 3D
# etc
/\# filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Кроме этого, я пытаюсь посмотреть, что же всё таки так много весит в основном хранилище гита, и почему его не забрало в LFS?

пишу

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack\pack-48da725c12c669fde2fdedccf3f88de0b9d31b75.idx
```

И получаю ответ

```
 fatal: Cannot open existing pack file '.git/objects/packpack- 
 48da725c12c669fde2fdedccf3f88de0b9d31b75.idx'
.git/objects/packpack-48da725c12c669fde2fdedccf3f88de0b9d31b75.pack: bad
```

Вопросы

1)Как мне узнать что за файлы занимают место в моём не ЛФС репозитории?

2)Как их удалить и вернуть репозиторию адекватный размер?

Добавлено:
`git lfs ls-files` выдает нормальный список тех файлов которые и должны быть в LFS
т.е. миграция сработала. 
`git ls-files` выдает просто список всех файлов, включая LFS и не LFS. Но вроде бы так и должно быть?

Comment: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#cleaning-up-the-git-directory-after-migrating там ещё рекомендуют `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all` перед git gc

Comment: @AlexeyTen
Спасибо! Оно действительно что то сделало, но итоговый 'size-pack' остался почти прежним 2.24 -> 2.23 ГБ

Comment: Не пользуйтесь Bitbucket'ом. Единственный хостинг, которым можно пользоваться -- либо свой собственный сервер, либо GitHub. Всё остальное сосёт (ради объективности стоит заметить, что BitBucket сосёт гораздо меньше других).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что репозиторий следил за веткой `origin/master`, чтобы была возможность сделать `checkout` на неё.
Поэтому он хранил информацию о ней в репозитории и от этого размер был такой большой. Просто удаляем сохранённую информацию на этой ветке и место в репозитории возвращается.

```
git branch -d -r origin/master
```

После нужно проверить что появился мусор(удалённая ветка) и почистить его

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Готово!

```
git count-objects -v -H
```

Выдает нам Size почти в два раза меньше.