# После удаления двух папок по 800 мегабайт, репозиторий прибавил в весе

Tags: git

(Сегодня я уже задавал похожий вопрос, ([Репозиторий больше 2 гб после миграции файлов на лфс && gc --aggressive --prune=now](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860185/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-2-%D0%B3%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%84%D1%81-gc-aggressive-prune)%D0%BD%D0%BE) они отличаются. Пожалуйста, не удаляйте. Просто у меня 2 компьютера, и я пытаюсь уменьшить размер репозитория разными способами.

Есть репозиторий в 2 гига, битбакет сказал надо уменьшать размер.

Есть две папки по 800 мегабайт, которые не нужны. Удаляем их из истории

```
GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE=1 git filter-branch--tree-filter 'rm -rf Assets/oneBadFolder && rm -rf Assets/second-bad-folder'
```

После этого размер репозитория увеличивается до фантастических 5.3 гигабайт! 
Но это понятно - он просто еще не почистил мусор. Делаем

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune-now
```

И размер становится 2.23 гига. До удаления этих папок из истории размер был 2.1 гига.

Вопрос - что я сделал не так? Почему операция удаления из истории двух папок по 800 мб и последующая чистка мусора привела в итоге к увеличению размера репозитория? И как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что репозиторий имел сохранённую копию, которая отображалась в виде отдельной ветки, на которую нельзя было переключится, и называлась она

```
original/refs/heads/master
```

Чтобы освободить место - надо убрать это сохранённую копию и сделать чистку мусора.

Внимание - проверьте что все файлы в вашем репозитории в порядке и проект работает и вообще всё хорошо - удаление резервной копии лишает вас возможности быстро вернутся на старый вариант.

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

И всё - размер репозитория падает почти в два раза.

Можно проверить

```
git count-objects -v -H
```